# Get extent of Georeferenced Rasters in Python and output to polygon shapefile

Tags: arcpy, raster, gdal, error-999999, error-000725

I would like to create a shapefile containing the extents of each of the rasters in a directory. Is it possible to capture the extent of a raster using Python?

I have tried

> > > extent1=arcgisscripting.Raster.extent('stg1_05.jpg')
> > >       Runtime error : 'getset_descriptor' object is not callable

and I can't seem to find any help on the module.

I also tried

> > > arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(inRaster, outPolygons, "SIMPLIFY", field)
>
> Runtime error : ERROR 010247: The size of the output shapefile exceeds the 2 GB limit. ERROR 010067: Error in executing grid expression. Failed to execute (RasterToPolygon).

Anyway this will be a polygon of the whole raster file and not just the extents -even if this is generated, I guess we could then run a merge/dissolve but the files created are to big.

Another option I was thinking of was to convert the raster to layer

```
import arcpy, glob, os, sys
from arcpy import env, mapping
path = os.getcwd()
env.workspace = path
RasterType = 'TIF'
FileList = glob.glob(path + "\*." + RasterType)

print 'Reading files from ' + path
os.chdir(path)
#print FileList

x=0
z=1005
File=FileList[x]
LayerWorking=arcpy.mapping.Layer(File)
print File
LayerExtent=LayerWorking.getExtent()
XMAX = LayerExtent.XMax
XMIN = LayerExtent.XMin
YMAX = LayerExtent.YMax
YMIN = LayerExtent.YMin
pnt1 = arcpy.Point(XMIN, YMIN)
pnt2 = arcpy.Point(XMIN, YMAX)
pnt3 = arcpy.Point(XMAX, YMAX)
pnt4 = arcpy.Point(XMAX, YMIN)
array = arcpy.Array()
array.add(pnt1)
array.add(pnt2)
array.add(pnt3)
array.add(pnt4)
array.add(pnt1)
polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array)
ShapeFile = path + "\Polygon_Extent" + "_" + str(z) + ".shp"
print ShapeFile
print arcpy.GetMessages()
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(path, ShapeFile, "POLYGON")
print arcpy.GetMessages()
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(polygon, ShapeFile)
```

Gives following output

> Reading files from C:\Python26\script_tests\rectify
>   C:\Python26\script_tests\rectify\Stage1_01a.TIF
>   C:\Python26\script_tests\rectify\Polygon_Extent_1005.shp Executing:
>   CopyFeatures in_memory\fB4DC2172_7D02_44B9_B55C_9E71427AE96E
>   C:\Python26\script_tests\rectify\Polygon_Extent_1004.shp # 0 0 0 Start
>   Time: Thu Jul 14 16:11:38 2011 Failed to execute. Parameters are not
>   valid. ERROR 000725: Output Feature Class: Dataset
>   C:\Python26\script_tests\rectify\Polygon_Extent_1004.shp already
>   exists. Failed to execute (CopyFeatures). Failed at Thu Jul 14
>   16:11:38 2011 (Elapsed Time: 0.00 seconds) Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File "C:\Python26\script_tests\rectify\temp.py", line 36, in
>   
>       arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(path, ShapeFile, "POLYGON")   File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\management.py",
>   line 1539, in CreateFeatureclass
>       raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. Failed to execute (CreateFeatureclass).

using IDLE...Which is wierd as when you run it from the Python window in ArcMap it works fine when the Create/Copy feature commands are run individually.

> ShapeFile = "Polygon_Extent" + "_" + str(z) + ".shp"
>   arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(path, ShapeFile, "POLYGON")
>
> > Result 'C:\Python26\script_tests\rectify\Polygon_Extent_1005.shp'>
>
> arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(polygon, ShapeFile)
>
> > Result 'C:\Python26\script_tests\rectify\Polygon_Extent_1005.shp'>

this seems to be a very convoluted process...

**UPDATE:**
I am trying to add the filename to the table and for some reason it inserts a new row into the table and doesn't accept "updateRow(row)"? what am I doing wrong? Also the files don't seem to retain the projection I assign them.

> Reading files from C:\Python26\script_tests\rectify C:\Python26\script_tests\rectify\Stage1_01a.TIF Created:
>   Polygon_Extent_1.shp Filled in 
>   C:\Python26\script_tests\rectify\Stage1_01a.TIF Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "C:\Python26\script_tests\rectify\ResterExtent_toSHP.py", line 45, in
>   
>       rows.updateRow(row)   File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\arcobjects.py", line
>   102, in updateRow
>       return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.UpdateRow(*gp_fixargs(args)))
>   RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.

**SCRIPT *all working now*.**

```
import arcpy, glob, os, sys, arcgisscripting
from arcpy import env, mapping
path = os.getcwd()
env.workspace = path
env.overwriteOutput = True
RasterType = 'TIF'
FileList = glob.glob(path + "\*." + RasterType)
print 'Reading files from ' + path
os.chdir(path)
#print FileList
geometry_type = "POLYGON"
template = "C:\\Python26\\GDA_1994_MGA_Zone_55.shp"
has_m = "DISABLED"
has_z = "DISABLED"
# Creating a spatial reference object
spatial_reference = arcpy.SpatialReference("C:\\Python26\\GDA_1994_MGA_Zone_55.prj")

x=0
z=x+1
for File in FileList:
#File=FileList[x]
    RasterFile = arcgisscripting.Raster(File)
    RasterExtent = RasterFile.extent
    print File
    XMAX = RasterExtent.XMax
    XMIN = RasterExtent.XMin
    YMAX = RasterExtent.YMax
    YMIN = RasterExtent.YMin
    pnt1 = arcpy.Point(XMIN, YMIN)
    pnt2 = arcpy.Point(XMIN, YMAX)
    pnt3 = arcpy.Point(XMAX, YMAX)
    pnt4 = arcpy.Point(XMAX, YMIN)
    array = arcpy.Array()
    array.add(pnt1)
    array.add(pnt2)
    array.add(pnt3)
    array.add(pnt4)
    array.add(pnt1)
    polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array)
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(path, "Temp_Polygon_Extent" + "_" + str(z), geometry_type, template, has_m, has_z, spatial_reference)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(polygon, "Temp_Polygon_Extent" + "_" + str(z))
    ShapeFile = "Temp_Polygon_Extent" + "_" + str(z) + ".shp"
    print "Created: " + ShapeFile
    arcpy.AddField_management(ShapeFile,'FileName','TEXT')
    desc = arcpy.Describe(ShapeFile)
    print desc, ShapeFile
    #rows = arcpy.InsertCursor(ShapeFile, desc)
    rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(ShapeFile)
    #row = rows.newRow()
    #row.FileName = str(File)
    #row.FileName = File
    print 'Filled in: ', str(File) 
    #rows.insertRow(row)
    for row in rows:
        row.FileName = str(ShapeFile)
        rows.updateRow(row)
    x=x+1
    z=z+1

#cleaning up
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(path, "Extent.shp", geometry_type, template, has_m, has_z, spatial_reference)
list =[]
lstFCs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Temp_Polygon_Extent*")
print 'Merging Polygon_Extents* to Extent.shp'

for fc in lstFCs:
    print fc
    list.append(fc)

arcpy.Merge_management(list, "Extent.shp")
#print 'Deleting identical entries and temp files'
#arcpy.DeleteIdentical_management("Extent.shp", ["SHAPE"])
print 'Created Extent.shp and exiting'

for item in list:
    arcpy.Delete_management(item) 
del row, rows
```

**GDAL Ver.**

```
import os, gdal
gdaltindex Extent.shp *.tif
```

> File "". line 1
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

BTW FTTools Python window is a pain as you can't copy/past code/errors from it to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost had it right with your first attempt. What you are doing is trying to call the `extent` property with a filename as its parameter, when you need to construct a `Raster` object with that parameter.

In practical terms, that means:

```
extent1 = arcgisscripting.Raster('stg1_05.jpg').extent
```

Although it is usually better practice to break it down into two steps:

```
raster1 = arcgisscripting.Raster('stg1_05.jpg')
extent1 = raster1.extent
```

Note the lack of parentheses on `extent`, this is because it is a property rather than a method.

Comment: Thanks mate. That worked great. I have uploaded the new code for anyone to use. Useful to generate the extents of all images in a directory so that they can be easily referenced. I will expand this to os.walk and all imagery types in due course...but I am having an issue with insert/update.Row. Please see updated post.

Comment: CORRECTED IT...all working fine now. Thanks Mersey.

Answer (score 2):

GDAL has a [`gdaltindex`](http://www.gdal.org/gdaltindex.html) command-line utility that does the same thing you are after:

```
gdaltindex Extent.shp *.jpg
```

The utility was intended for tile indexing for MapServer, but it works just the same for any other purpose. One caveat (which is the same for your script) is that it does not rotate the polygon footprint for rotated rasters.

Comment: thanks. I haven't been able to get GDAL to work in my ArcGIS python install yet so I haven't been able to try any GDAL based solutions.

Comment: Yeah, it's tricky to install older GDAL versions for the same version of Python from ArcGIS. I install OSGeo4W to keep it separate from Esri software, then run the commands in their "OSGeo4W Shell". FWTools also work just the same.

Comment: Thanks mike. I do have GDAL in my FWTOOL (forgot that I did). I am getting errors though. See the ticket please.

Comment: The commands need to be used in a FWTools Shell .. not a Python console